# Save/ import style of chart symbology in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, style, chart, layer-file

I am trying to save a style for a chart symbology. I can save it as .lyr file but I can't import the .lyr file into the chart symbology after: it says "this symbology option is not supported for importing". I can't import the symbology from another layer also, the list of layers shows up empty. Another option is the import dialogue via an ArcView 3 legend file (avl), I can't try this option since I don't have avl files.

I don't have tons of shapefiles so I will not try with scripting, just wondered if there is any simple solution I am missing out on? Next problem is I can't change labeling of the symbology, I was going to solve this in the end by converting the legend to graphics.

Comment: there are color schemes and they can be edited, so if there was an option to create a good color scheme I could use that. But the "edit" options are very restricted and confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a work-around for the symbology, no solution for labels though. Good to know is that there are different types of color schemes, which have different edit-options, i.e. algorithmic/ multi-part.

1. In Properties/ Symbology/ Charts/ Pie choose an algorithmic color scheme from the drop-down list (smooth transitions from one color to the next).
2. right-click on the drop-down list button (arrow), choose "Properties".
3. select the first algorithmic color ramp, click on "Properties", set the color you want for the first pie of the chart as "Color 1" and "Color 2".
4. add as many pies with different colors as you need.

When you are finished, click "OK" and again right-click on color scheme selection button to save your style. It should be listed as color scheme in the selection then. To access it, change it, delete it ... go to Customize/ Style Manager/ yourComputer/ Color Ramps.